# How to install packeges in Android via ADB Shell

Tags: android, adb

I have android connected to a windows machine. I need to install some list of required packages (seems they are lost). How I can install the package(for example, this one is from the list):

/system/app/vsimservice/vsimservice.apk=com.sec.vsimservice

to my android device

Thank you for your thoughts in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to search for missing apks (I believe that's what you meant, not packages) on sites like this one https://apkpure.com/sim-card-detail-vsim/com.vtool.vsim.simcardinfodetail - but it's not 100% success guaranteed story as it all depends on hardware platform + the rest of software ecosystem on your device (versions, flavors etc).

Comment: Could work, but the device has it. When I try to install it, I got "ERROR [-30001]" in response without any additional message